# Error when creating Azure function App

Tags: azure, azure-cli, azure-function-app-proxy

I'm am following the steps here on this tutorial to [automatically create image thumbnails](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-grid/resize-images-on-storage-blob-upload-event)

I get to the step to create the function app by running this code (replacing all relevant values):

```
az functionapp create --name <function_app> --storage-account <general_storage_account>  
\ --resource-group myResourceGroup --consumption-plan-location westcentralus
```

At any stage after this step, if I view the function app in the portal I receive the following error and am unable to find the cause `The function runtime is unable to start. Please check the runtime logs for any errors or try again later. Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection: The payload was invalid.`

Comment: Hi, do you create storage account and create function app? Do them in Azure Cloud shell?

Comment: I test in my lab, I don't meet your error log, if possible, could you create function app in Azure Portal and check again. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-create-function-app-portal

Comment: @ShengbaoShui-MSFT Yes, I created a general storage account and the function in Azure cloud shell. I'll try and create it in the portal.

Comment: @ShengbaoShui-MSFT The error is no longer displaying today. Whilst this is good in a way, it makes me uncomfortable that the error has gone overnight without any intervention.

Comment: I'm actually not sure that it will help anyone as the error has simply gone on it's own with no action being taken.

Comment: It search on google, it seems a storage account issue. If possible, I suggest you could create a new storage account and test again :--).

Comment: Hi, see this link https://github.com/Azure/Azure-Functions/issues/226 But I think you could not meet the error log if you create function app on Portal.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/161687/discussion-between-shengbao-shui-msft-and-fishcake).

Comment: Hi, currently everything is ok?

Answer (score 0):

The issue seems to be related to:
https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk-script/issues/2072

If in case you are using Website_ContentShare setting (which means using the same storage account) you might face this issue.

Go to https://.scm.azurewebsites.net/DebugConsole
Go into data -> functions
Delete the secrets folder
If that doesn't work:

browse to the storage account for your function app into the azure portal,
go into containers -> azure-webjobs-secrets
delete the container with your function app name e.g. the circled entry in this screenshot:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R3374.png)